# Looping through API calls in Python to create one dataset with an indicator variable

Tags: python, loops

I am attempting to stack different years of the same dataset. However, my looping through different API calls isn't working; only the first dataset is coming through, and I'm not sure why.

```
# Define the APIs and category fields
api_endpoints = [
    "https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/3pjd-kfu4.json",
    "https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/7xqa-efsz.json", 
    "https://data.cityofchicago.org/resource/anck-gptm.json"
]

indicators = ["2009-2010", "2010-2011", "2011-2012"]

# Stack data from API calls, indicate dataset year

def stacky(api_endpoints, indicators):
  dataframes=[]

  for endpoint, indicator in zip(api_endpoints, indicators):
    response = requests.get(endpoint)
    data=response.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['Category'] = indicator
    dataframes.append(df)

    combined = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)

    return(combined)

# Create the DataFrame using the function
addresses = stacky(api_endpoints, indicators)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is only executing once because the return statement is inside of it. Back the last two lines out one indentation and it should work. For example

```
def stacky(api_endpoints, indicators):

  dataframes=[]

  for endpoint, indicator in zip(api_endpoints, indicators):
      response = requests.get(endpoint)
      data=response.json()

      df = pd.DataFrame(data)
      df['Category'] = indicator
      dataframes.append(df)

  combined = pd.concat(dataframes, ignore_index=True)
  return(combined)
```

Comment: Thank you! It has been a while since spacing has wrecked my day, so I was overdue. I appreciate it and have marked it as the solution.